Dialogflow CX Webhook partial response does not work in an Integration
The problem is that in the Test Agent -> Simulator everything works fine. But in actual integration like Google Chat and Dialogflow Messeger partial response does not work and the message "Wait a second. I'll look up the database." is displayed with Webhook info.
I've tried to send the user a message: "Wait a second. I'll look up the database." before calling Webhook to improve user experience. To do so I used google docs. I've added a Webhook request to the same page as a message for a user to wait and used a conditional route in order to display info from Webhook on the next page.
